# Popular Articles Algorithm w/ Decay

Tags: php, algorithm, formula, trending

Building a feature of top of existing site w/ articles and videos (posts) that allows people to see what is popular on the site. I have the following fields for each post:

- Number of seconds since post was published
- Number of comments made on post
- Number of "likes" on posts

I want to bake a simple algorithm to determine what is popular but need to factor in decay (from time being elapsed).

Comment: just playing with my own. like variations of: 

(n_likes * 2) + (n_comments * 4) / (n_seconds / (60 * 60 * 24))

I think I am missing some of the magic of established trending algorithms.

Comment: There is no magic. You just need to clearly define your specification. When you have clearly identified the bounds and effect of decay, the code will be easy to write.

Comment: a Google search for [popularity algorithm with decay] brings up lots of good results. Also see the related questions about trending topics algorithms such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143781/what-is-search-twitter-coms-trending-topics-algorithm

Comment: Usually things like `e^(- a t + b * comments + c * likes)`  work pretty well. You should choose {a,b,c} to fit your preferences

Comment: This was most helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143781/what-is-search-twitter-coms-trending-topics-algorithm

Comment: You should also probably have a the number of seconds since the last post.  For example if the post was made a long time ago but there is still a steady stream of comments on it, you probably want that to show up higher than a post that was made a long time ago and was very popular (got a lot of comments) but only for a day or two after it was made.